# How to use jquery masonry with livequery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How to re-arrange the DIVs while hiding the div tag.

```
// jquery masonry plugin
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',

  });

// Delete
$(".item").click(function()
{
$(this).hide();

// Here I want to call 
});


// HTML Code
  <div id="container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
----
----
----
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to call in `// Here I want to call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do? Reload? Remove the item?

```
$(".item").click(function()
{
 $(this).hide();  
 //Remove item
 $('#container').masonry( 'remove', $(this) );
 //Reload masonry
 $('#container').masonry( 'reloadItems' );
});
```

Comment: I want to re-arrange the DIVs

Comment: To re-arrange all DIVs you need to reload again

 `$('#container').masonry('reload'); `

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983204/jquery-masonry-remove-function-example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery's DOM manipulation functions, see this http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ , to ease your job if you give a unique id to each div it should be easier to re-order them any way you want

Comment: I want to re-call this for every div delete action $('#container').masonry()